# Typescript | how to use array to manipulate the values in dropdown

Tags: typescript, react-bootstrap

I have to implement a dropdown using React & Bootstrap & TypeScript. How can I do that? Dropdown values like these `years = ["2018",2019","2020","2021"]` will come from props like this:

```
Export interface Csprops{ years:string[] }
export const Cs=({ years, }:CsProps):JSX.Element =>{ }
```

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: years=["2018",2019","2020","2021"] coming from props 

Export interface Csprops{
years:string[]
}

export const Cs=({
years,
}:CsProps):JSX.Element =>{

}
Here i want to use react bootstrap to display these values how can i do that?

Comment: you should show some attempts of yours if you want better answers and your question reopened. Please do your best, edit the question and provide more details. If you attempts fail for some reason, explain it, see also [mcve]. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the react-bootstrap default dropdown here is a sample, assuming years is a constant, if it is a props you can pass it to this function as props and call it as `props.years`.

You will need an onClick listener when you change the year and make it a current selectedYear state.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Container, Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const years = ["2018", "2019", "2020"];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState("");

  function yearsDropdown() {
    return years.map((year) => (
      <Dropdown.Item
        onClick={() => setSelectedYear(year)}
        href={`#year-${year}`}
      >
        {year}
      </Dropdown.Item>
    ));
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Dropdown>
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
          {selectedYear || `Select Year`}
        </Dropdown.Toggle>
        <Dropdown.Menu>{yearsDropdown()}</Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: But when i am doing this it's giving error saying type'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: Yes i am using typescript

Comment: The code above is valid to typescript, the only time this is not a valid typescript code is if there is a custom interface, so the code above is compatible to typescript. Do you have a custom interface, react-bootstrap is built in to accept the children like that, can you at least post your code?